# Google Script not sending email as html

Tags: google-apps-script, html-email

I have set up a script to notify users when a new entry has been submitted to a shared spreadsheet.  I am trying the following, but the emails are getting sent as plain text:

```
function formSubmitReply(e) {
  var emailAddress = ' *email addresses* ';
  var URL = ' *URL to send as link* ';
  var message = "<HTML><BODY>"
   + "<P>" + " A new guest complaint has been entered into the database."
   + '<P>To view the spreadhseet, <A HERF="' + URL + '">click here</A>.'
   + "</HTML></BODY>";

MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, "New Guest Complaint", "", {htmlBody: message});
}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the sample in the official docs
, where it uses the htmlBody parameter: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app#sendEmail(Object)
You are including html and body tags when the parameter expects the body html not an html page. Remove those tags. Also, note that your tags at the end are reversed (/html then /body)